# Object[object Object] has no method 'slitslider'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting the error `'Object[object Object] has no method 'slitslider'` when trying to implement a slider on my page. I don't know quite much of javascript so I don't really know why this is happening.

This is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(function() {

        var Page = (function() {

            var $nav = $( '#nav-dots > span' ),
                slitslider = $( '#slider' ).slitslider( {
                    onBeforeChange : function( slide, pos ) {

                        $nav.removeClass( 'nav-dot-current' );
                        $nav.eq( pos ).addClass( 'nav-dot-current' );

                    }
                } ),

                init = function() {

                    initEvents();

                },
                initEvents = function() {

                    $nav.each( function( i ) {

                        $( this ).on( 'click', function( event ) {

                            var $dot = $( this );

                            if( !slitslider.isActive() ) {

                                $nav.removeClass( 'nav-dot-current' );
                                $dot.addClass( 'nav-dot-current' );

                            }

                            slitslider.jump( i + 1 );
                            return false;

                        } );

                    } );

                };

                return { init : init };

        })();

        Page.init();

        /**
        * Notes: 
        * 
        * example how to add items:
        */

        /*

        var $items  = $('<div class="sl-slide sl-slide-color-2" data-orientation="horizontal" data-slice1-rotation="-5" data-slice2-rotation="10" data-slice1-scale="2" data-slice2-scale="1"><div class="sl-slide-inner bg-1"><div class="sl-deco" data-icon="t"></div><h2>some text</h2><blockquote><p>bla bla</p><cite>Margi Clarke</cite></blockquote></div></div>');

        // call the plugin's add method
                ss.add($items);

        */

    });
</script>
```

I guess it has something to do with the other jquery files that are loaded but I'm not sure how to solve it. This is the generated HTML:

```
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.ba-cond.min.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.slitslider.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap.min.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/turbolinks.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/application.js?body=1"></script>
```

**UPDATE**

HTML:

```
<div class="container demo-2">

    <header class="clearfix">

        <h1>Slit Slider <span>with CSS3 and jQuery</span></h1>

    </header>

    <div id="slider" class="sl-slider-wrapper">

        <div class="sl-slider">

            <div class="sl-slide" data-orientation="horizontal" data-slice1-rotation="-25" data-slice2-rotation="-25" data-slice1-scale="2" data-slice2-scale="2">
                <div class="sl-slide-inner">
                    <div class="bg-img bg-img-1"></div>
                    <h2>A bene placito.</h2>
                    <blockquote><p>You have just dined, and however scrupulously the slaughterhouse is concealed in the graceful distance of miles, there is complicity.</p><cite>Ralph Waldo Emerson</cite></blockquote>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="sl-slide" data-orientation="vertical" data-slice1-rotation="10" data-slice2-rotation="-15" data-slice1-scale="1.5" data-slice2-scale="1.5">
                <div class="sl-slide-inner">
                    <div class="bg-img bg-img-2"></div>
                    <h2>Regula aurea.</h2>
                    <blockquote><p>Until he extends the circle of his compassion to all living things, man will not himself find peace.</p><cite>Albert Schweitzer</cite></blockquote>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="sl-slide" data-orientation="horizontal" data-slice1-rotation="3" data-slice2-rotation="3" data-slice1-scale="2" data-slice2-scale="1">
                <div class="sl-slide-inner">
                    <div class="bg-img bg-img-3"></div>
                    <h2>Dum spiro, spero.</h2>
                    <blockquote><p>Thousands of people who say they 'love' animals sit down once or twice a day to enjoy the flesh of creatures who have been utterly deprived of everything that could make their lives worth living and who endured the awful suffering and the terror of the abattoirs.</p><cite>Dame Jane Morris Goodall</cite></blockquote>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="sl-slide" data-orientation="vertical" data-slice1-rotation="-5" data-slice2-rotation="25" data-slice1-scale="2" data-slice2-scale="1">
                <div class="sl-slide-inner">
                    <div class="bg-img bg-img-4"></div>
                    <h2>Donna nobis pacem.</h2>
                    <blockquote><p>The human body has no more need for cows' milk than it does for dogs' milk, horses' milk, or giraffes' milk.</p><cite>Michael Klaper M.D.</cite></blockquote>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="sl-slide" data-orientation="horizontal" data-slice1-rotation="-5" data-slice2-rotation="10" data-slice1-scale="2" data-slice2-scale="1">
                <div class="sl-slide-inner">
                    <div class="bg-img bg-img-5"></div>
                    <h2>Acta Non Verba.</h2>
                    <blockquote><p>I think if you want to eat more meat you should kill it yourself and eat it raw so that you are not blinded by the hypocrisy of having it processed for you.</p><cite>Margi Clarke</cite></blockquote>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /sl-slider -->

        <nav id="nav-dots" class="nav-dots">
            <span class="nav-dot-current"></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
        </nav>

    </div><!-- /slider-wrapper -->

    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <h2>About this slider</h2>
        <p>The Slit Slider is a slideshow with a twist: the idea is to slice open the current slide when navigating to the next or previous one. Using jQuery and CSS animations we can create unique slide transitions for the content elements. </p>
    </div>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(function() {

        var Page = (function() {

            var $nav = $( '#nav-dots > span' ),
                slitslider = $( '#slider' ).slitslider( {
                    onBeforeChange : function( slide, pos ) {

                        $nav.removeClass( 'nav-dot-current' );
                        $nav.eq( pos ).addClass( 'nav-dot-current' );

                    }
                } ),

                init = function() {

                    initEvents();

                },
                initEvents = function() {

                    $nav.each( function( i ) {

                        $( this ).on( 'click', function( event ) {

                            var $dot = $( this );

                            if( !slitslider.isActive() ) {

                                $nav.removeClass( 'nav-dot-current' );
                                $dot.addClass( 'nav-dot-current' );

                            }

                            slitslider.jump( i + 1 );
                            return false;

                        } );

                    } );

                };

                return { init : init };

        })();

        Page.init();

        /**
        * Notes: 
        * 
        * example how to add items:
        */

        /*

        var $items  = $('<div class="sl-slide sl-slide-color-2" data-orientation="horizontal" data-slice1-rotation="-5" data-slice2-rotation="10" data-slice1-scale="2" data-slice2-scale="1"><div class="sl-slide-inner bg-1"><div class="sl-deco" data-icon="t"></div><h2>some text</h2><blockquote><p>bla bla</p><cite>Margi Clarke</cite></blockquote></div></div>');

        // call the plugin's add method
                ss.add($items);

        */

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Do you actually have a div in your HTML that has the id `slider`?

Comment: Yes:     <div id="slider" class="sl-slider-wrapper">. Would it help if I updated the question with the whole HTML?

Comment: Yes, give it a go, can't see anything wrong at the moment.

Comment: It would help if you make a http://jsfiddle.com.

Comment: I believe that this guy (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13456290/script-stops-the-execution-of-other-code-slitslider) had the same problem but since I don't know much about javascript I can't really understand the answer

Comment: Use Chrome developer tools (network tab) to verify if all javascript files are loading fine. Just Refresh the page, and all js files should load fine i.e. 200 OK.

Comment: Check the `$( '#slider' ).length`, should not be an `0`.

Comment: I'm sorry @Piyuesh. I've just checked again and I'm getting a Not Found error on the file bootstrap.map.css. I'm not sure why this is happening because I'm actually not calling for this file...

Comment: @nightire How can I actually do this? As I said I'm very new to javascript

Comment: @LeoCosta `console.log($('#slider').length)`, it this selector actually works, it should give you a non-0 number, should be `1` since  you use ID selector.

Comment: Where are you loading your libraries?

Comment: @MMM on my application.css.scss file

Comment: @nightire I'm not sure the code is problem because when I downloaded the source code from here (http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/06/05/fullscreen-slit-slider-with-jquery-and-css3/) it worked fine. When I tried to implement it on my app, that's where the problems started

Comment: That's just because of some minor changes you made! Put it online to let us check it.

Comment: @nightire I managed to solve the problem. It was actually the order of the jquery files being loaded. Thanks for all the help anyways